# Как при нажатии на inline кнопку отобразить текст в окне?

Tags: python, aiogram, aiogram-2.x

как сделать inline кнопку, при нажатии на которую текст будет выводиться вот в таком окне? Библиотека aiogram
[image: текст в окне]

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/480693

Comment: cпасибо, помогло

Comment: а что делать если это сообщение выложено в канал?

Comment: @CrossTick а вы пробовали в канале сделать?

Comment: всё, для канала нужно было просто один параметр изменить и всё заработало, спасибо